# How to replace a same value in multiple rows JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, tabs

I would like to change all the values of a column in a table every time I get a new value.
For this, I have a JS code (JQuery) and an HTML code.
JQuery allows me to replace values with ".replaceWith". However, instead of replacing all the time values, it displays me one by one. First column = time 1, second column = time 2 etc.
Would it be possible to do this differently without having to declare a new ID for each row? Thanks a lot.

(The CSS is not done yet, sorry for the questionable readability)

**JS CODE**

```
content2 = '<td>' + epochToDateTime(timestamp) + '</td>';
                  $('#tbody2').replaceWith(content2);
                  content3 = '<td>' + Com_success_rate + '</td>';
                  $('#tbody3').replaceWith(content3);
                  content4 = '<td>' + PLC_communication_failure + '</td>';
                  $('#tbody4').replaceWith(content4);
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<tr>
<td></td> 
<td>%D3 id= </td>
<td>ALM_LOCAL_COM@1</td>
<td>PLC communication failure</td>
<td id="tbody4"></td>
<td id="tbody2"></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<td></td> 
<td>%DW4 id= </td>
<td>LOCAL_COM_RATE@1</td>
<td>Com success rate</td>
<td id="tbody3"></td>
<td id="tbody2"></td>
</tr>
```

And what I get in the website : [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhyPm.png)

Comment: You are not supposed to have more then one element with the same id. `$('#tbody2')` will always return the first element and ignore the (invalid) remaining ones.

Comment: It also looks like you just want to change the text? You can do `$('tr').each(function (i) { $(this).find('td')[0].text(someValueArray[i]); });`

Comment: Also this would not be valid `'<td>' + PLC communication failure + '</td>'`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I forgot to put "_", thank you !

Comment: I used a selector to resolve my problem. Thank you for your answers !